# How to implement OCL(Object Constraint Language) in JAVA

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am working on a JavaEE project, and I have to implement OCL (Object Constraint Language), I search a lot, but I didn't find how to implement it.
Can someone give me an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an OCL implementation https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdt.ocl

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework from IBM called JRules which is an example of

[Business Rules Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule_management_system), but it's too complicated and bulky.

You just need to do it manually then or using such frameworks as [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/)

Answer (score 0):

AgileUML has Java code generators from UML/OCL: for versions 4, 6, 7 and 8 of Java (https://github.com/eclipse/agileuml). There are some videos on using the tool at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKAK9eITDkw&t=41s